# Highcharts pie slice linear gradient

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a small question:
Is it possible to create using `highcharts` something like this - http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/317/index.html

I know, that i can create pie with radial gradient - http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient , but i want create linear gradient for each pie slice (as in canvas example above).

Answer (score 0):

Unforuantely this kind of gradients are not supported, but you can post your suggeston on our [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com) website and vote for it.